# Word implying this object is required by another

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I'm looking for a word that has the opposite implication to "depends on" or "has this prerequisite". Something which describes the relationship of B to A if A is a prerequisite of B.

Something that could mean "dependor" or "requirer", for example?

Comment: The way I see it, the title of the question is asking for the opposite thing from the body. It is also asking for an adjective, while "dependor" and "requirer" are nouns.

Comment: Whoops, it's late and I did a bad grammar.

Updated to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If B requires A, then B is dependent on A. So B is a **dependent** of A.

> Dependent: (adj) determined or conditioned by another : contingent (e.g., plans
>   that are dependent on the weather) [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dependent)

The corresponding noun has the same spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, we might say: [If A is necessary for B, then B is sufficient for A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Relationship_between_necessity_and_sufficiency). Then B is a sufficient condition for A.

Assume that if A is a prerequisite of B, then A must be completed before B starts; otherwise, A would be a corequisite with respect to B. Then B is [*subsequent to*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsequent) A. The same webpage says *subsequent* is also a noun, so B is A's *subsequent*.

[*Contingent*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contingent) is similar. But I think it's more general because it is not related to "sequence"; B needs A, but B doesn't always happen when A does.

Comment: I think "contingent upon" (or "contingent on") represents exactly the meaning OP is looking for, but I don't think there is a noun of the type he is seeking to convey this relationship.

Comment: Good point. I found a noun [*contingency*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contingency) (as in "B is a contingency of A"). Something about it feels a little off to me, but it looks like it should be valid by the definition. Does it look right to you?

Comment: Contingent appears to also be [a noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contingent) meaning "something contingent".  I seems interchangable with "contingency", but I'm not sure.