# Word for 'that which requires something'?

Tags: single-word-requests

If `A` requires `B`, then `B` is the **requirement**. In this relationship what is `A`?
In this context, I'm describing academic courses where `B` is a course that fulfills the requirements for course `A`.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109995/

Comment: What is the context? A purchase? A contract?

Comment: You could say A is the "dependent".  Could you get away with calling it a "contingent"?

Answer (score 2):

At my university (in the United States Midwest), one would say "ECE 700 (A) is a *follow-on course* to ECE 600 (B)" and while this implies that B is a prerequisite, it doesn't necessarily *require* it.

(In my department at least, prerequisites were pretty flexible: transfer students, grad students, and students from other departments---as well as those just plain motivated---could very easily get them waived, so avoiding the suggestion of strict requirements was usually intended.)

Answer (score 0):

B is a *prerequisite* of A. That is common terminology for students registering for classes.

[*Prerequisite* is defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prerequisite)

> adj.
>   Required or necessary as a prior condition: Competence is prerequisite to promotion.
>
> n.
>   Something that is prerequisite, as a course that is required prior to taking an advanced course.

Comment: But the question is what word designates A's relationship to B?

Comment: ......dependent

Comment: @StoneyB, Oooh...you're actually correct. I guess I addressed the OP's second sentence, but not the actual question. A class that has prerequisites might be called *an advanced, more advanced, or upper level class.*